# When message will be reaccepted by kafkaListener in case of ack absence?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Let's say I have spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so76481597", topics = "so76481597")
    void listen(String in, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) int del) throws InterruptedException {
        log.warn(in + ":" + del);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        log.warn(in + ":" + del + " finished");
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so76481597").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so76481597", "foo");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> containerCustomizer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory) {

        ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> cust = container -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
            container.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
            container.setConcurrency(3);
        };
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(cust);
        return cust;
    }
}
```

As you can see I setup AckMode.MANUAL and don't call ack manually. My expectations that message should be redilivered after some timeout ?

Could I control this timeout ?

Could I control amount of repeats ?

On practice I see:

```
2023-06-16 14:46:11.081  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:16.096  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 14:46:16.097  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:21.104  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 14:46:21.104  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:26.108  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 14:46:26.128  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:31.134  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 14:46:31.134  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:36.148  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 14:46:36.148  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:41.160  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 14:46:41.160  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 14:46:46.174  WARN 35328 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
```

So

1. Next (the same) message is accepted just after previous listener is finished. It is weird a bit for me. What will be if application is shutdown during mesasge habdling ?
2. Application tries to accept message 9 time and then stopped to try. Can I configure it ?

### Update

I tried to restart application multiple times and delivery amount was always different. Sometimes - 2 times like here

```
2023-06-16 15:58:26.741  WARN 28160 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 15:58:36.755  WARN 28160 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
2023-06-16 15:58:36.756  WARN 28160 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1
2023-06-16 15:58:46.757  WARN 28160 --- [o76481597-0-C-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : foo:1 finished
```

sometimes - 3, sometimes 7. So the amount is  not determined. Why ?

Comment: You control the repeats by acking (commit the offset), or otherwise manually seeking the consumer forward

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Could you explain what is going on in case of ack absence ? why method listen is called multiple times ? why this process is not infinite ?

Comment: As far as I know the delivery in Kafka doesn't work that way. There is a cursor for consumer on the topic partition and in the perfect world we never need to commit offsets (ack in your terms) and consumer always forward to the next offset after the current delivery. A committed offset makes sense only after restart. At this point the consumer group takes a committed offset and starts consuming from there. Therefore you'll see those redeliveries only after restart if you don't ack.

Comment: @Artem Bilan so why do I see the behaviour I described in the topic ? method "listen" is called multiple times. You can easily run my code to make sure I don't lie.

Comment: Because you send a new data on application start and consumer reads this one and previously not committed. You'll see difference when you also log a `KafkaHeaders.OFFSET` header in your `listen()` method.

Comment: @Artem Bilan si if I change the topic name and restart the app - I should receive a single message ?

Comment: Actual reults:
1 start - 1;
2 start - 4;
3 start - 6;
4 start - 8;
5 start - 9;
6 start - 11;
7 start - 13;

Any ideas why ?

Comment: when I setup concurrency to 1 - results became more predictable
1 start - 1;
2 start - 2;
3 start - 3;
4 start - 4:
5 start - 5;

Comment: If you change the topic name, then it is fully different story and you must not receive data from other topics. It is probably better to test the behavior without sending a new message on restart again and again.

Comment: @Artem Bilan looks like it is related to the  concurreny option (please read prvious comment) even with send on startup

Comment: The concurrency must not matter: you just have `partitions(1)`, so only one consumer will be active.

Comment: @Artem Bilan could you please run the code from the topic  for a single time ?

You will find "foo:1 finished" twice

Comment: Probably your `Thread.sleep(5000);` is too long and it causes a rebalance on consumer group and this way a new consumer after rebalance will rewind to its committed offset.

Comment: @Artem Bilan I removed timeout and result still the same

Comment: And concurrency really matters(just try)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot: it is not easy to have a dedicated Apache Kafka on Windows. The embedded doesn't fit our scenario and I would need some effort to start it in the Docker.

Comment: BTW I use bitnami/kafka:latest image

Comment: I assume you're using latest Spring-kafka?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I use spring-boot 3.0.4 and spring-kafka from corresponding release train(I don't provide version explicitly)

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see I setup AckMode.MANUAL and don't call ack manually. My expectations that message should be redilivered after some timeout ?

No; Kafka doesn't work that way. It maintains 2 pointers, the current position and the committed offset, after the consumer starts, they are unrelated, failing to ack a record will not cause it to be redelivered until you restart the consumer (and then only as long as you haven't acked a following record in the same partition). Polls only return records from the current position; committing offsets is independent.

You have to throw and exception, and the default error handler will re-seek the partition and the record will be redelivered.